# JFrame : cannot display two panels in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have problem to display two panel in Jframe. Please help me to fix the code below

```
public class quotingtable extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JTable table;
    JButton SetButton = new JButton("Set Symbol");
    JButton VNStock = new JButton("VNStockChart");
    JButton Global = new JButton("GlobalChart");
    JPanel quotingpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel functionpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

public void run(){
    model = new DefaultTableModel(col,row);
    quotingpanel.add(table);
    functionpanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,SetButton);
    functionpanel.add(BorderLayout.WEST,VNStock);
    functionpanel.add(BorderLayout.EAST,Global);
    table = new JTable(model);

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    quotingpanel.add(pane);
    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,functionpanel);
    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,quotingpanel);
    setSize(800,800);
    setLayout( new FlowLayout());
    setLayout ( new BorderLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove `setLayout( new FlowLayout());` and `setLayout ( new BorderLayout());` which appear at the end of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove:

```
setLayout( new FlowLayout());
setLayout ( new BorderLayout());
```

Using `BorderLayout` this way won't pick up the pre-existing components, so will ignore them and won't lay them out

And consider replacing `setSize(800,800);` with `pack();`

You may also want to change

```
getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,functionpanel);
getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,quotingpanel);
```

to

```
getContentPane().add(functionpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(quotingpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

it's simply a more consistent and preferred mechanism